# Map groups to roles in Keycloak when using OIDC

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I have Azure AD connected to Keycloak via OpenID Connect. I want to do the following:

- If user "Romeo" is a member of the group "Montague" in AD, he should have the role "lover" in Keycloak
- I don't want to import all AD groups and users, users are imported on first login
- the role "lover" is defined in Keycloak
- this should work on the realm level and work the same for different clients

All examples I could find only explain how to do this using LDAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surprisingly difficult, but possible. Heres how:

- Azure Active Directory does not return group memberships by default. To activate it:

  - go to your app registration
  - go to Manage > Manifest
  - set the value for the "groupMembershipClaims" key to "All", so that the line looks like this: `"groupMembershipClaims": "All",`
  - save
- Keycloak does not request the `groups` scope per default. To do this:

  - in the Keycloak Admin UI, go to Configure > Client Scopes
  - click "create"
  - enter name: "groups"
  - enable "Include In Token Scope"
  - enable "Display On Consent Screen"
  - save
  - then, add the `groups` scope to the "Default Client Scopes"
- still in Keycloak, go to your identity provider

  - create a new mapper
  - Mapper Type: "Claim To Role"
  - Claim: "groups"
  - Claim Value: enter the **Object ID**, *not* the name of the AD group that you wish to use as the trigger for role assignment
  - Role: select the desired role
  - save